# React Routing not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am using React routing v4 for a application that has a login and a home page once a dumb auth is done. 
As of this point I have this LoadComponent.jsx in my index.js file:

```
    class LoadComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoggedOn: false,
  };

  onLoginCheck = (name, password) => {
    console.log(name, password);
    if (name && password) {
      setTimeout(name, 100); // fake async
      console.log('set the timeout');
    }
    this.setState({
      isLoggedOn: true,
    });
  };


  checkAuth = () => {
    const { isLoggedOn } = this.state;
    console.log('checking auth: ', isLoggedOn);
    return (isLoggedOn);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter >
        <Switch>
          <Header isLogged={this.checkAuth()} />
          <Route path="/login" render={props => <Login isLoggedOn={this.state.isLoggedOn} onLoggedInCheck={this.onLoginCheck} {...props} />} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/" component={App} authenticated={this.state.isLoggedOn} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

My privateRouter looks like the following :

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
  component, exact = false, path, authenticated,
}) => {
  console.log('here : ', authenticated);
  return (
    <Route
      exact={exact}
      path={path}
      render={props => (
        authenticated ? (
          React.createElement(component, props)
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location },
          }}
          />
        )
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

The only thing that is rendered on the page is the Header component which makes sense, but the PrivateRoute component is not functioning since at first the Login component should be displaying. Im not sure what I am doing wrong here since I have followed the react router Redirect Auth example to some degree.